# go install -a -race std fails when go is installed using gvm

Tags: shell

`go install -a -race std`

if i manually install go the above command works if i install using 
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz

`$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go install -a -race std`

```
# cmd/gofmt
runtime.raceinit: undefined: runtime/race.Initialize
runtime.raceinit: undefined: runtime/race.MapShadow
runtime.racefini: undefined: runtime/race.Finalize
runtime.racewrite: undefined: runtime/race.Write
runtime.raceread: undefined: runtime/race.Read
runtime.racefuncenter1: undefined: runtime/race.FuncEnter
runtime.racefuncexit: undefined: runtime/race.FuncExit
runtime.racemalloc: undefined: runtime/race.Malloc
runtime.racefree: undefined: runtime/race.Free
runtime.racegostart: undefined: runtime/race.GoStart
runtime.racegoend: undefined: runtime/race.GoEnd
rangeaccess: undefined: runtime/race.WriteRange
rangeaccess: undefined: runtime/race.ReadRange
runtime.raceacquireg: undefined: runtime/race.Acquire
runtime.racereleaseg: undefined: runtime/race.Release
runtime.racereleasemergeg: undefined: runtime/race.ReleaseMerge
runtime.racefingo: undefined: runtime/race.FinalizerGoroutine
prctl(0): not defined
pthread_attr_destroy(0): not defined
pthread_attr_getstack(0): not defined
pthread_getattr_np(0): not defined
too many errors
These are the errors i got when i ran that command
$echo $GOPATH 
/home/mrinal/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.1/global

$echo $GOARCH 
amd64

$echo $GOOS 
linux

$echo $GOROOT 
/home/mrinal/.gvm/gos/go1.1
```

My system uses ubuntu 16.04 .Its a linux based system.I think the option race with the command gvm is not being supported for this particular version.